# CURL Sends Requests Twice For Single Request

Tags: php, url, curl, url-encoding, php-curl

I am using the following code to send a CURL request to send a SMS. But the SMS is being sent twice.

```
    $message = urlencode($message);
    $smsurl = "http://$url/sendmessage.php?user=matkaon&password=$password&mobile=$mobile&message=$message&sender=$sender&type=3";
    $ch = curl_init($smsurl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $sentsms = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

I tried commenting some of the lines which solved the issue but gives an output as below:
[image]

What is the proper method to send a CURL request only once?

Comment: yes it is. The problem it's probably on the sendmessage.php file

Comment: @andre_vieira I do not control `sendmessage.php`, it is with the SMS service provider.

Comment: curl_init($url) with parameter will exec the query, use curl_init() and then later curl_exec($url)

Comment: What made you conclude the curl call was the culprit? Your sample code does not involve any logging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $smsurl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_exec($ch);
```

Don't pass the URL as argument on the init function.

I don't know why the function is being called twice, but I never pass the URL as argument and always work great this way.

Answer (score 0):

You'd usually use `curl_init()` with no parameters, then pass the URL into `curl_exec`.

Modified example 1 from [`curl_exec` docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php):

```
<?php
// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $smsurl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
curl_exec($ch);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
?>
```